# Function argument contravariance with respect to type: any

Tags: typescript

In TS we know functions are contravariant with respect to arguments.
Which means if we have this situation:

```
class User {
  username: string;
 
  constructor(username: string) {
    this.username = username;
  }
}
 
class Admin extends User {
  isSuperAdmin: boolean;
 
  constructor(username: string, isSuperAdmin: boolean) {
    super(username);
    this.isSuperAdmin = isSuperAdmin;
  }
}

type Func<Param> = (param: Param) => void;

type IsSubtypeOf<S, P> = S extends P ? true : false;
```

Then this:

```
type T31 = IsSubtypeOf<Func<Admin>, Func<User>> //false
```

should be `false` because `User` is **supertype** of `Admin`.

But now, when I substitute `User` with `any` **which is also supertype of** `Admin`, result `T32` is true. Why?

```
type T32 = IsSubtypeOf<Func<Admin>, Func<any>> //true
```

So in both above situations I just used two types `Admin` and `any` both are **supertypes** of `User`, but **the result was different.**

Comment: `any` is also a subtype of `Admin`; if you have a value of type `any` then you can assign it to a variable of type `Admin`. That's just how `any` works, and how it is supposed to work. The proper "top type" in TS is `unknown`.

Comment: @kaya3 so it is also a subtype and supertype ?

Comment: Yes. It's unsound, the purpose of `any` is to disable type-checking.